# Understanding Expectation Calculation in Bayesian Inference

Tags: probability, probability-theory

In [this short paper](http://www.nature.com/nbt/journal/v22/n9/full/nbt0904-1177.html) the author sets up a game where Alice is playing Bob in a game involving independent Bernoulli trials.  The first to six points wins, where Alice gets one point for a "success" and Bob gets one point for a "failure."  The score is currently 5-3 with Alice winning, so Bob needs three "failures" of consecutive, independent Bernoulli trials to win, for which $P(\text{Bob wins} \mid A = 5, B = 3) = (1-p)^3$, where $A = 5, B = 3$ means the current score is 5-3 with Alice winning.

The author then treats the probability $p$ as a random variable and gives the formula,
$$
E(\text{Bob wins}) = \int_0^1(1-p)^3 \, P(p \mid A = 5, B = 3) \, \mathrm{d} p,
$$
which is the first equation in the paper.  The author then states, "... the $P(p \mid A=5, B=3)$ term is the probability that that particular choice of $p$ is the correct one, given the observed data that the score is Alice 5, Bob 3."

My question is, is the author's explanation really correct?  It seems like the term represented by $P(p \mid A=5, B=3)$ should really be a probability density function.  Moreover the quantity $E(\text{Bob wins})$ is really the expected value of the conditional probability that Bob wins, given the score is 5-3, so we should have $E(\text{Bob wins}) = E(P(\text{Bob wins} \mid A = 5, B = 3))$.  Finally, it seems we really need to treat the quantity $P(\text{Bob wins} \mid A = 5, B = 3)$ as a *function of the random variable* $\mathbf{p}$ (bold to emphasize it is now a random variable, $\mathbf{p}: [0,1] \to [0,1]$). That is, 
$$
P(\text{Bob wins} \mid A = 5, B = 3)(\mathbf{p}) = (1-\mathbf{p})^3.
$$
Let me try to rewrite the expectation value formula above, and I ask you to verify it is the proper way to do so.  Let $([0,1], \mathcal{B}[0,1], Q)$ be the probability space that $\mathbf{p}$ is defined on and denote a realization of $\mathbf{p}$ by $\mathbf{p}(\omega) = p$.  Assume there is a probability density function $f_{\mathbf{p}}: [0,1] \to [0,\infty)$ for $\mathbb{p}$.  As an aside, note we need at most 11 trials to determine a winner, so the probability space $(\Omega, \mathcal{F}, P)$ for the game described above is 
\begin{align*}
\Omega & = \{\text{all sequences of "successes" and "failures" of length 11}\}, \\
\mathcal{F} & = 2^\Omega.
\end{align*}

So, the expectation value formula above should read,
\begin{align*}
E(P(\text{Bob wins} \mid A = 5, B = 3)) = E((1-\mathbf{p})^3) & = \int_{[0,1]} (1-\mathbf{p}(\omega))^3 \, \mathrm{d} Q(\omega) \\
& = \int_0^1 (1-p)^3 \, f_{\mathbf{p}}(p) \, \mathrm{d} p.
\end{align*}

Would this be the proper rigorous way of describing this situation?

**Update** The probability density function $f_{\mathbf{p}}$ should really be a conditional probability density function, conditional on the current score being 5-3.  That is, we should define it as $f(\cdot \mid \cdot): [0,1] \times \Omega \to [0,\infty)$ and write $f(p \mid A=5, B=3)$ in place of $f_{\mathbf{p}}$ in the integral above.  But then, how should I be thinking of the expectation $E((1-\mathbf{p})^3)$, which I've written as an unconditional expectation?

Comment: That expectation is also conditional.

Answer (score 1):

First of all yes and yes.  What the author is calling $P(p|A=5,B=3)$ is a density, this is common notation for continuous random variables.  And yes the author is computing $\mathbb{E}(\text{Bob Wins} | A=5,B=3)$.

I wouldn't get to caught up in the formalization because I think it lead you to miss the important Bayesian aspect of the problem.  The current score not only tells us what needs to happen for Bob to win, it also gives us information about the random variable $\mathbf{p}$.  Therefore in the integral instead of integrating against whatever (prior) distribution we believed $\mathbf{p}$ was drawn from we are integrating against the updated posterior distribution given the values drawn from the Bernoulli distribution.

Comment: Good point on the integral should be using the conditional distribution.  Do you think you could shed light on my update?

Comment: Thanks for the comment.  Would you also clarify why the author is computing $\mathbb{E}(\text{Bob Wins} \mid A=5,B=3)$ and not $\mathbb{E}(P(\text{Bob Wins}) \mid A=5,B=3)$?  I don't see where the $(1-p)^3$ in the integral would come from otherwise.